# How to get keys and values separately from List<KeyValuePair<Type,object>>?

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, get, key-value

I would like to get the keys and values and store them in separate arrays.how can this be done in c# VS2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var keys = list.Select(i => i.Key).ToArray()
var values = list.Select(i => i.Value).ToArray()
```